# How to cross-compile a Go project from Linux to Windows on Travis-CI

Tags: go, travis-ci, cross-compiling

Because Travis-CI native windows support for Go seems to be lacking,
I though about going this route.

How would I best do that?

Answer (score 0):

This builds natively for Linux, natively for OSX, and cross compiles for windows, as part of the linux build:

`.travis.yml`:

```
language: go
sudo: false

matrix:
  include:
    - go: tip
      os: linux
      env: CROSS_COMPILE=true
    - go: tip
      os: osx

before_install:
  - if [ "$CROSS_COMPILE" = "true" ]; then sudo apt update; fi

install:
  - if [ "$CROSS_COMPILE" = "true" ]; then sudo apt install gcc-mingw-w64 libc6-dev-i386; fi
  - go get github.com/some/go-dependency
  - go get -t -v ./...

script:
  - go build
  - go test
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" -a "$CROSS_COMPILE" = "true" ]; then env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -v; fi
```